# Location class using CLLocationManager in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I new to iOS. I have an app that allows the user to update their location in different view controllers. I am trying to minimize the amount of code to do this, so instead of duplicating the methods to achieve this, I put all the location related methods in a separate class.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class LocationUtil: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

   func findUserLocation()->Void{
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

from my view controller I am calling this class like so.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let locUtil = LocationUtil()
        locUtil.findUserLocation()

}
```

however, none of the delegate methods get called.  When I use the same code directly in a view controller it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `locUtil`, to which you have assigned your LocationUtil instance, is an automatic variable — that is, it is local to the `viewDidLoad` function. Thus, when `viewDidLoad` runs, `locUtil` (and your LocationUtil instance) comes into existence, exists for one more line, and vanishes in a puff of smoke. Your LocationUtil instance is thus destroyed once more — taking its instance variables, such as the location manager, with it.

Thus there is no time for anything to happen. The location manager and its delegate exist for about a millionth of a second. That is not long enough to work out your location!

Comment: The solution is to make `locUtil` an instance variable (a property) of your view controller - not a local variable. That will give whatever you assign to it persistence for as long as the view controller itself lives.

Comment: However, please note that that is not what you asked! Your question was not how to do it right; you asked what you were doing wrong. My answer explained that.

Comment: If you want `locUtil` to live even longer, make it an instance variable (property) of your AppDelegate instance, which lives as long as the app runs. Variable declarations are all about scope and lifetime!